# Dedupe - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'indexAll'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dedupe

I'm using [dedupe library](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe) and everything works fine until training data is used for dedupe but while calculating the threshold with the same data set it gives the following error:

```
deduper.threshold(data_d, recall_weight=2)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'indexAll'
```

My data set:

```
{23347895: {'Address': '100 Kanoki street drive',
  'Id': '23347895',
  'Name': 'kanoki',
  'Unname': 'brunswick',
  'no': '1',
  'zip': '41092'},
 2543294: {'Address': '1005 Main Street',
  'Id': '2543294',
  'Name': 'kushal gore',
  'Unname': 'brunswick',
  'no': '2',
  'zip': '41093'}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Could you open an issue https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/issues